# want to connect two devices through blue tooth only once

Tags: iphone, xcode

My question is that I want to connect two iphone's or ipod's through bluetooth and after that I can send sound files between two devices, my question is that once the two devies are connected successfully through bluetooth I can not want to connect more than one time through blue tooth

Comment: Do you want to do that in a program you are writing?  What have you tried already?

Comment: I implement a project in which it connect two devices through bluetooth and after that I will send the data from one device to another and if I want to send another data then again I connect two devices and after that I send the data to one device, I do not want this, I only want that when the two devices connect each other and after I do not want to connect these devices after once

Comment: You want to disconnect the connection with other device after sending the file.

Comment: @Anand I want to conect two or more devices only once, and after that I will transfer the data to each other deveices, that's it